# Pass variables from shell script to Perl script

Tags: perl, ksh

I'm trying to send two values from my existing shell code to a Perl script, which needs to be processed. I'm relatively new to perl, and I tried accepting them using the ARGV[0] and ARGV[1], but when I try to print the values, they come out to be blank. I cannot seem to understand the problem here, although from this it looks like, the Perl script didn't get the values. The variables hold strings and I verified them by printing in the shell script.

I used two syntaxes based on solutions available, however none of them seem to work:
There are 2 variables BITNUM and BITENV, which I'm passing:

```
In the shell script I did:
/scriptdirectory/execute.pl $BITNUM $BITENV
To accept them in Perl I did:
my $var1 = $ARGV[0];
my $var2 = $ARGV[1];
print "Var 1 is $var1\n";
print "Var 2 is $var2\n";
```

This did not work so I tried using export in the Shell script

```
export BITNUM
export BITENV
/scriptdirectory/execute.pl $ENV{"BITNUM"} $ENV{"BITENV"}
```

To accept them in Perl I did:

```
my $var1 = $ENV{BITNUM};
my $var2 = $ENV{BITENV};
print "Var 1 is $var1\n";
print "Var 2 is $var2\n";
```

Both of these return blank values. Is this occurring because I've passed multiple values and there's another way of doing this which I've not tried?

Comment: Please check this url https://alvinalexander.com/perl/edu/articles/pl020002/

Comment: *"This did not work.."* Are you sure `BITNUM` is defined? What is the output of `perl -E 'say $ARGV[0]' $BITNUM` ?

Comment: `/scriptdirectory/execute.pl $ENV{"BITNUM"} $ENV{"BITENV"}` : You cannot use Perl hashes (like `%ENV`) from the shell. Instead use `$BITNUM` (to access the environment variable `BITNUM`) instead of `$ENV{BITNUM}` in the shell

Comment: You don't need to pass the variables as command-line arguments, nor should you. Merely by marking the shelll variables as exported, their values will appear to perl within the %ENV hash.

Comment: Another way to verify the values from shell: `env | grep '^BIT'` -- if you haven't actually assigned values, that command will return no lines.